# How to show rows in MS Access that has enddate<startdate?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Basically I want to check if any end dates are earlier than the start date (which would be wrong). Therefore I decided to check the right 4 characters of the string and compare with a greater than. The code works but nothing happens even when I change the dates to be intentionally wrong. The format is mm/dd/yyyy.

```
SELECT *
FROM [myTable]
WHERE
RIGHT ('EndDate',4)<RIGHT ('StartDate',4)
;
```

The table given to me wrote the date columns in 'Short Text'. I can change it to date, but then I am not too sure how to use `DATEDIFF()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RIGHT('EndDate',4)` and `RIGHT ('StartDate',4)` each return the 4-character string, *Date*.  So your query's `WHERE` condition was equivalent to `'Date' < 'Date'`, which was False for every row.  Don't put the field names inside quotes.

And date comparisons are less troublesome with Date/Time values instead of dates as strings.  Use `CDate()` to cast your date strings to real Date/Time values.  Then the comparison is straightforward ...

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable AS m
WHERE CDate(m.EndDate) < CDate(m.StartDate);
```

If it's practical to change those fields' datatypes to Date/Time, the query could be simpler and perform faster.

Comment: Thanks, this worked exactly as I wanted. May I ask what is the meaning of the 'm.*' as it has the same effect as just SELECT *. 

Is it a way to define the table instead of typing the entire 'myTable' out everytime?

Comment: I used `m` as an alias for the table name.  So `m.*` means all the fields from the `m` data source, which is actually `myTable`.  Since this query has only one data source, `SELECT m.*` is equivalent to `SELECT *`.  But the alias doesn't really add value to this query; I just routinely alias my data sources out of habit.

Answer (score 2):

For string comparing use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [myTable]
WHERE
RIGHT ([EndDate],4)<RIGHT ([StartDate],4)
```

But it won't work for dates within one year because you compare only years. It would work for date format yyyy/mm/dd, `Right` function not needed in this case.

Best solution - convert text to date using `CDate` and use the same operator for comparing - "<"

Comment: Woops, posted at the same time as you. What do you mean it wont work for different years?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited answer.